# Need help to understand polymorphism

Tags: c#, polymorphism

The classes below consist of

**A** - father class

**B** - Child class

**Holder** - Contains a list of A's

I want to reach a child property from the list of fatherobjects. Why cant I do this? Or better question, how do I do this?

```
public class A
{
    public int var = 0;
}

public class B : A
{
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
    public int Property2 { get; set; }

    public B()
    {

    }

    public B(B p_B)
    {
        Property1 = p_B.Property1;
        Property2 = p_B.Property2;
    }
}

class Holder
{
    private List<A> m_Objects = new List<A>();

    public void AddObject(A p_Object)
    {
        m_Objects.Add(p_Object);
    }

    public void AddObjectProperty1(B p_B)
    {
        // At this point, m_Objects holds a B-object. And I want to add the value from Property1
        // but there is no Property1 in the A-class so I cant do this. How do I use the base.values from 
        // a statement like the one below?
        int index = m_Objects.FindIndex(item => item.Property1 == p_B.Property1);
        if (index > -1)
            m_Objects.ElementAt(index).Property1 += p_B.Property1;
    }
}


class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Class to hold the objects
            Holder h = new Holder();

            // Create a B object
            B b = new B();
            b.Property1 = 1;
            b.Property2 = 2;

            // Place a new instance of the B-object in a list of A's
            h.AddObject(new B(b));

            // Add the value from Property1 to the value in the b-object in the a-list.  :P
            h.AddObjectProperty1(b);

            Console.WriteLine(++b.var);
            Console.ReadLine();


        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't name your variable `var`. First, it doesn't mean anything, second, `var` is also a keyword in C# - your code will get messy and difficult to maintain.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your advice! :) I usually dont name variables var, I was just trying to create somethign as generic as possible at this particular case! But thanks for noticing it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use type casting:

```
(m_Objects[i] as B).Property1
```

Or

```
((B)m_Objects[i]).Property1
```

Comment: Ty for you answer! I tried this solution but Property1 is not recognized even though the typecasting is correct. :(

Comment: What do mean: not recognized. It don't compile or crash with an error or you get null value?

Answer (score 0):

At compile-time there is no possibility for the compiler to know, you would only add `B`s to your list of `A`s. So there is no guarantee whatsoever that each `item` in the following query is an instance of `B` and thus has `Property1`

```
int index = m_Objects.FindIndex(item => item.Property1 == p_B.Property1);
```

First possibilty is casting as in Artyom's answer. But this will fail if you not all of the elements in the List are really `B`s. So if you rely on all Elements in `m_Objects` to be instances of `B`, why don't you just use `List<B> m_Objects`?

If you need the mixed list, you have to do a type-check in the query to ensure, you are dealing with an instance of `B`before casting.

```
int index = m_Objects.FindIndex(item => (item is B) && (item as B).Property1 == p_B.Property1);
```

See this [DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TTXUc7)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. The reason I want to store B's in A's and not the other way around is that I want to use polymorphism to store objects in a way I find smart (which may not be the case). For example, if the holderclass is a wallet. I want to store Cash (read as A) which can be in form of coins or bills (B or C if C existed). The sound of that sounds good for me, since I can just have a list of Cash. I tried your solution, and the syntax was correct, however Property1 is not found when casting item :( Any clues? Am I thinking the wrong way of this?

Comment: From that point of view, using a `List<A>`absoultely makes sense.

What do you mean by 'Property1 is not found'? See the updateded [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2Qx9KT). Seem to work as expected.